# Rewrite Rules for HTTP to HTTPS Redirect

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect all http://thesite.com, http://www.thesite.com, https://thesite.com to https://www.thesite.com.  But I don't have the pattern correct.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPs" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
           <rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^thesite.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.thesite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
```